# How to return data in JSON format using FastAPI?

Tags: python, json, serialization, fastapi

I have written the same API application with the same function in both **FastAPI** and **Flask**. However, when returning the JSON, the format of data differs between the two frameworks. Both use the same `json` library and even the same exact code:

```py
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

@router.get('/report')
async def report(request: Request):
    response = get_clicks_impression(bigquery_client, source_id)
    return response

def get_user(client, source_id):
    try:
        query = """ SELECT * FROM ....."""
        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
            query_parameters=[
                bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("source_id", "STRING", source_id),
            ]
        )
        query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)  # Wait for the job to complete.
        result = []
        for row in query_job:
            result.append(dict(row))
        json_obj = json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

    return json_obj
```

The returned data in **Flask** was dict:

```json
  {
    "User": "fasdf",
    "date": "2022-09-21",
    "count": 205
  },
  {
    "User": "abd",
    "date": "2022-09-27",
    "count": 100
  }
]
```

While in **FastAPI** was string:

```
"[\n    {\n        \"User\": \"aaa\",\n        \"date\": \"2022-09-26\",\n        \"count\": 840,\n]"
```

The reason I use `json.dumps()` is that `date` cannot be itterable.

Comment: You're returning a string in FastAPI, so it will return a string. Don't serialize it yourself - instead, return the object and FastAPI will serialize it for you. It should handle date/datetime just fine: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-data-types/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### The wrong approach

If you serialise the object before returning it, using `json.dumps()` (as shown in your example), for instance:

```py
import json

@app.get('/user')
async def get_user():
    return json.dumps(some_dict, indent=4, default=str)
```

the JSON object that is returned **will end up being serialised twice**, as FastAPI will *automatically* serialise the return value behind the scenes. Hence, the reason for the output string you ended up with:

```json
"[\n    {\n        \"User\": \"aaa\",\n        \"date\": \"2022-09-26\",\n ...
```

## Solutions

Have a look at the available solutions, as well as the explanation given below as to how FastAPI/Starlette works under the hood.

### Option 1

The first option is to return data (such as `dict`, `list`, etc.) as usual— i.e., using, for example, `return some_dict`—and FastAPI, behind the scenes, [will automatically convert that return value into JSON](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/), after first converting the data into JSON-compatible data, using the [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/). The `jsonable_encoder` **ensures** that objects that are not serializable, such as [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) objects, are converted to a `str`. Then, FastAPI will put that JSON-compatible data inside of a [`JSONResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=jsonresp#jsonresponse), which will return an `application/json` encoded response to the client (this is also explained in Option 1 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804)). The `JSONResponse`, as can be seen in Starlette's source code [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/858629f5188bc79d452600b1eb90eaa0045f6454/starlette/responses.py#L181), will use the Python standard `json.dumps()` to serialise the `dict` (for alternatvie/faster JSON encoders, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804)).

##### Example

```py
from datetime import date


d = [
    {"User": "a", "date": date.today(), "count": 1},
    {"User": "b", "date": date.today(), "count": 2},
]


@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return d
```

The above is **equivalent** to:

```py
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder(d))
```

**Output:**

```json
[{"User":"a","date":"2022-10-21","count":1},{"User":"b","date":"2022-10-21","count":2}]
```

Returning a `JSONResponse` or a custom `Response` directly (it is demonstrated in Option 2 below), as well as any other response class that inherits from `Response` (see FastAPI's documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/), as well as Starlette's documentation [here](https://www.starlette.io/responses/) and responses' implementation [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/responses.py)), would also allow one to specify a **custom** `status_code`, if they will. The implementation of FastAPI/Starlette's `JSONResponse` class can be found [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/da7adf246de5495b154b45e32d6fa95e181993d8/starlette/responses.py#L185), as well as a list of HTTP codes that one may use (instead of passing the [HTTP response status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) as an `int` directly) can be seen [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/da7adf246de5495b154b45e32d6fa95e181993d8/starlette/status.py#L11). Example:

```py
from fastapi import status
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder(d), status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

### Option 2

If, for any reason (e.g., trying to force some custom JSON format), you have to serialise the object before returning it, you can then [return a custom `Response` directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#returning-a-custom-response), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72246260/17865804). As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#notes):

> When you return a `Response` directly its data is **not** validated,
> converted (serialized), nor documented automatically.

Additionally, as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=jsonresp#response):

> FastAPI (actually Starlette) will automatically include a
> Content-Length header. It will also include a Content-Type header,
> based on the `media_type` and appending a charset for text types.

Hence, you can also set the `media_type` to whatever type you are expecting the data to be; in this case, that is `application/json`. Example is given below.

**Note 1**: The JSON outputs posted in this answer (in both Options 1 & 2) are the result of accessing the API endpoint through the browser directly (i.e., by typing the URL in the address bar of the browser and then hitting the enter key). If you tested the endpoint through Swagger UI at `/docs` instead, you would see that the indentation differs (in both options). This is due to how Swagger UI formats `application/json` responses. If you needed to force your custom indentation on Swagger UI as well, you could avoid specifying the `media_type` for the `Response` in the example below. This would result in displaying the content as *text*, as the `Content-Type` header would be missing from the response, and hence, Swagger UI couldn't recognise the type of the data, in order to custom-format them (in case of `application/json` responses).

**Note 2**: Setting the `default` argument to `str` in [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) is  what makes it possible to serialise the `date` object, otherwise if it wasn't set, you would get: `TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable`. The `default` is a function that gets called for objects that can't otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON-encodable version of the object. In this case it is `str`, meaning that every object that is not serializable, it is converted to string. You could also use a custom function or `JSONEncoder` subclass, as demosntrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable), if you would like to serialise an object in a custom way. Additionally, as mentioned in Option 1 earlier, one could instead use alternative JSON encoders, such as `orjson`, that might improve the application's performance compared to the standard `json` library (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804)).

**Note 3**: FastAPI/Starlette's [`Response`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/858629f5188bc79d452600b1eb90eaa0045f6454/starlette/responses.py#L38) accepts as a `content` argument either a `str` or `bytes` object. As shown in the implementation [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/858629f5188bc79d452600b1eb90eaa0045f6454/starlette/responses.py#L60), if you don't pass a `bytes` object, Starlette will try to encode it using `content.encode(self.charset)`. Hence, if, for instance, you passed a `dict`, you would get: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'`. In the example below, a JSON `str` is passed, which will later be encoded into `bytes` (you could alternatively encode it yourself before passing it to the `Response` object).

##### Example

```py
from fastapi import Response
from datetime import date
import json


d = [
    {"User": "a", "date": date.today(), "count": 1},
    {"User": "b", "date": date.today(), "count": 2},
]


@app.get('/')
async def main():
    json_str = json.dumps(d, indent=4, default=str)
    return Response(content=json_str, media_type='application/json')
```

**Output:**

```json
[
    {
        "User": "a",
        "date": "2022-10-21",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "User": "b",
        "date": "2022-10-21",
        "count": 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Heavily based and building on @Chris answer:

TL;DR:

For the first option, if you are using e.g. pandas first do e.g.:

```
JSONResponse(df.fillna(np.nan).replace([np.nan], [None]).to_dict())
```

For the second
second answer,
**do not send extra spaces by using indent**, but do it like this:

`Response(content=json_str, media_type='application/json')`

Reasons:

The first options fails if you try to send any nan value, even if it is one value on a long table or pandas, and so it might work now for your try, but in the future might fail (Murphy -> will fail). Fix is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62691803/508907).

For the second part, any indent that is not 0 is for human consumption and will not help your code run faster. Consider modern packages even often remove the indentation of javascript for pages. If debugging is needed, indenting the message is something any computer will be happy to do for you, and your favorite piece of code will be happy to indent is with exactly as many spaces you (the observer, as opposed to the one writing the code) is comfortable with.

[Answer changed based on comments. Also check comments for more. Especially if streaming.]

Comment: The json encoder does not allow `NaN` values. Thus, to use Option 1, you would have to replace `NaN` values in the `DataFrame`, using, for instance, `df = df.fillna('')`. Since you are dealing with a pandas `DataFrame`, you may want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804).

Comment: Good points, more research is needed to see which solution is best... (especially when streaming, on your 3rd link)... I am now uncertain which option is best

Answer (score 0):

use `response_class=JSONResponse`:

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
@app.get("/db/{jobid}", include_in_schema=True, response_class=JSONResponse)
async def dbget(jobid:int):
    """ read data stored on the jobid """
    return db.read(f"jobid=={jobid}")
```

[image: prove this works]

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The default `response_calss` is `JSONResponse`, regardless. Please have a look at the accepted answer above for more details.

Comment: @chris added a screenshot showing this works just fine. It is strongly discourage to not explicitly set response_class

Comment: I am afraid you are mistaken. Straight from the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/): _"**By default**, FastAPI will return the responses using `JSONResponse`"_. Again, please take a closer look at the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804). Also, please avoid posting images of code, data, response messages, etc. - instead, copy or type the text into the answer (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for more details).