# fastapi will messing sorted dictionary up

Tags: python, fastapi

Although I am returning a sorted dictionary by value, FastAPI response is not sorted.

I'm using

- python: 3.8.10
- fastapi: 0.95.2

###### This is my endpoint:

```bash
@classifier_router.post("/groupClassifier")
async def group_classifier(
    # current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user),
    group_id: str = Query(default="1069302375", description=GROUP_ID_DESC),
    starttime: Union[datetime , None] = DEFAULT_START_TIME,
    endtime: Union[datetime , None] = DEFAULT_END_TIME):
    result = handler.group_classifier(
        [group_id],
        starttime,
        endtime)
    if result==None:
        raise HTTPException(
        status_code=500
        )
    else:
        return result
```

###### Result which returned in swagger:

```
{
  "class_scores": {
    "1": 34.8,
    "2": 22.1,
    "3": 16.9,
    "4": 7.8,
    "5": 26,
    "6": 23.6
  }
}
```

Comment: You might find [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question first, In FastAPI when you return a dict in your endpoint, it will use it's internal [json encode](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/) to serialize your output, in this case it probably uses something like: `json.dumps(..., sort_keys=True)` by default.
To avoid that you can return a `JsonResponse` directly:

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@classifier_router.post("/groupClassifier")
async def group_classifier(
    # current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user),
    group_id: str = Query(default="1069302375", description=GROUP_ID_DESC),
    starttime: Union[datetime , None] = DEFAULT_START_TIME,
    endtime: Union[datetime , None] = DEFAULT_END_TIME):
    result = handler.group_classifier(
        [group_id],
        starttime,
        endtime)
    if result is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500)
    return JSONResponse(content=result)
```

on other note, if order is important for you, maybe using a dict is not the most appropriate data structure, you should probably look into returning a list of dicts, or simply a list with the index of the class score being the equivalent of the key

Comment: Thanks. Now output is sorted but output is not in json format: `"{\"class_scores\": {\"1\": 34.4, \"5\": 26.0, \"6\": 23.4, \"2\": 22.1, \"3\": 16.9, \"4\": 7.8}}"`

Comment: my bad, `JsonResponse` takes a dict as input. Looking at the source code it doesn't seem to run `sort_keys` on the dict so it should be safe:
https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/responses.py#L167

Comment: I changed return. But output is not sorted yet.

Comment: As @obendidi wrote, if you want the response sorted, don't use a dictionary. Even if your JSON is sorted, there is no guarantee it remains sorted in the receiving client. If order is important, use an array, something like `{"class_scores": [{"score": 1, "percentage": 34.8}, {"score": 2, "percentage": 22.1}, ...]}`