# FastaAPI return as JSON

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

```py
def get_all(db: Session):
    data = db.query(table).with_entities(table.id.label('id'), table.name.label('name')).all()
    return data
```

I am getting a `ValueError`:

```
TypeError('cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')
```

Earlier I was using the same code and I was getting no errors. But I updated FastAPI and Pydantic to the latest version the issue start to occur.

I am trying to get the JSON.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 0):

you should try `return data.dict()`

but I really think you should be using some orm here

Answer (score 0):

If its a generic dictionary you can use the dict to make the conversion although in other cases you may need to write a serializer function that processes correctly all data from the format that the db returned to the desired format