# How to return plain text in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

In this example, the entrypoint http://127.0.0.1:8000/ returns formatted text:

`"Hello \"World\"!"`

The quotes are masked by a slash, and quotes are added both at the beginning and at the end. How to return unformatted text, identical to my string `Hello "World"!`.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/",)
def read_root():
    return 'Hello "World"!'


uvicorn.run(app)
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) might help you better understand what takes place behind the scenes, when returning a response from a FastAPI app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you return a string from a FastAPI endpoint, FastAPI will automatically convert it to a JSON response, which is why the quotes are being escaped in your example. JSON strings must escape double quotes with a backslash.

If you want to return unformatted text (plain text) and not JSON, you can do so by using FastAPI's `PlainTextResponse` object ([docs here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#plaintextresponse)).

I'm using FastApi version 0.104 here:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.get(
    "/",
    response_class=PlainTextResponse,
)
def read_root():
    return 'Hello "World"!'


uvicorn.run(app)
```